Alternative theorems about system of (strict and weak) linear inequalities
I am looking for a proper version of Theorems of Alternatives to help me check the existence of solutions to the following system of linear inequalities:
Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, $B$ be a $l \times n$ matrix, $a \in R^m$, $b \in R^{l}$, whether there exists $x \in R^n$ such that
$$\begin{cases} 
Ax \geq a \\
Bx \gg b
\end{cases}$$,
where by $\geq$ I mean each of the inequalities is weak, and $\gg$ means all the inequalities are strict.
I have looked for several variations of Farkas' alternative, and the closed I found is Motzkin's Alternative, which deals with inequalities like this:
$$\begin{cases} 
Ax \gg 0 \\
Bx \geq 0\\
Cx = 0
\end{cases}$$
Is it an easy extension from some Alternative theorem to the system of inequalities I described above?
